# "Where will you go" vs. "Where you will go"

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

Which sentence is correct between these?

1. > Where will you go?
2. > Where you will go?

Comment: Since there were originally no question marks, but you indicated their "being a sentence", I edited and added them. Roll back if your general intention is modified. || Note that 2) is a perfectly grammatical construction, just, **not** a separate sentence. I can easily imagine this: ***Where you will go** isn't my concern.*

Answer (score 3):

Number 1 is correct.

When we construct a statement -- not a question -- in English, we normally phrase it subject / verb / object. Like "You / go / to the store." When there's a "helping verb", like "will" or "do", it goes with the verb. "You / will go / to the store."

But when we construct a question in English, it's normally "interrogative word / helping verb / subject / regular verb / object". By "interrogative word" I mean a word like who, when, where, how, etc. So, "Where / will / you go?" "Why / did / Bob / leave?" Etc.

Answer (score 3):

They are both correct depending on the context in which it is put.

1. Where will you go? 
   This is a direct question which needs a direct answer.

EXAMPLE
Question: Where will you go?
Answer: London.

2. Where you will go?
   This could be a response to what someone has said and in some way can be rhetorical.

EXAMPLE
John: I don't know where I will go
Mabel: Where you will go?

Answer (score 1):

In questions you have inversion of subject and verb, i.e. the subject is in position 2:

Are you British?

Have you seen it?

Can you talk English?

Do you understand me?

In questions with question words the subject is in position 3:

Why are you here?

When did you see it?

Why have you done this?

Who can we trust?